# Locally-Stored Fonts Are Not Being Rendered

Tags: html, css, font-face

I have this organization scheme:

- `foo/index.html`
- `stylesheets/normal.css`
- `stylesheets/fonts/example.woff`

`foo/index.html` contains:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../stylesheets/normal.css" />
 </head>
 <body>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
 </body>
</html>
```

`stylesheets/normal.css` contains:

```
@font-face
{
 font-style: normal;
 font-variant: normal;
 font-weight: normal;
 font-stretch: normal;
 font-family: "Example";
 src: url("fonts/example.woff");
}

p
{
 color: blue;
 font-family: "Example";
}
```

When I load `foo/index.html` in the browser on the machine local to these files (so not a webserver), the paragraph does not display with the `stylesheets/fonts/example.woff` font; but it does display with the blue color.

If I move `foo/index.html` to `index.html` (so it is not in a directory) and change the stylesheet path from `../stylesheets/normal.css` to `stylesheets/normal.css`, the paragraph is then properly displayed with the font.

Why is this happening? I am using Firefox version 52.0.2.

Comment: try using an absolute path to the stylesheet in foo/index.html `/stylesheets/normal.css`

Comment: If I set the stylesheet link to be absolute (`/home/username/project/stylesheets/normal.css`) in `foo/index.html`, the font is not displayed but the color blue is. If I set the stylesheet link to be absolute in `index.html` (same as `foo/index.html` but not in a directory), the font does display.

Comment: im pretty sure this is just a path issue, id fiddle around with your paths until it works.  Maybe try changing the url in the css files.

Comment: I have tried changing the paths a lot and nothing seems to work. I think this might be a browser bug.

Comment: What do you mean locally stored? Inside localhost or your local server? Or on desktop or anywhere outside your local server??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean locally-stored font and working inside a local server for example localhsot, you need to put the chosen font to your server or you need to work on your server for example with your localhost. 

To make the code more reliable,include an indicator of the font file type. You can use **EOT (Embedded OpenType)** files for Internet Explorer and either **OTF (OpenType)** or **TTF (TrueType)** for the rest. (Additional options include **WOFF (Web Open Font Format)** and **SVG (Scalable Vector Graphics)**. I use another optional efficiency measure, I use **`src: local('fontname')`** to get the browser to check for a local copy of the font in case the user already has it. In  addition you can include font variants font-weight. 
If you try to work on your desktop for example it didn't work or nothing happen, for that way you need to use `<style>@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arvo');</style>` for example.

foo/index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>STACKOVERFLOW | QUESTION 43509510</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../stylesheets/normal.css">
</head>
<body style="font-family: 'AceFont';">
    <h1 class="firsth1">This is my sample header</h1>
    <p class="firstparagraph">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
    consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
    proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

stylesheets/normal.css

```
/*The locally imported font*/
@font-face {
    font-family: 'AceFont';
    src: url('fonts/AriosoNormal.eot');
    src: local('AceFont'), url('fonts/AriosoNormal.woff') format('woff'), url('fonts/AriosoNormal.ttf') format('truetype');
}
/*End of the locally imported font*/

/*Content Sample*/
h1{
    font-family: 'AceFont';
}
.firstparagraph{
    font-family: 'AceFont' !important;
}
```

Download complete file here https://www.dropbox.com/s/k30nr5z6yywzg9z/localfont.rar?dl=0 . Please try the following code put in your server. And try again to put outside the server and see the difference.

Linking Google Fonts.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>STACKOVERFLOW | QUESTION 43509510</title>

    </head>
    <body style="font-family: 'Arvo', serif;">
        <h1 >This is my sample header</h1>
        <p >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </body>
    </html>

    <style type="text/css">
        @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arvo');
    </style>
```

Comment: I downloaded the RAR you provided and I discovered the following information: when I opened `foo/index.html` I did not see the font that you specified in the stylesheet. When I copied `foo/index.html` to `index.html` (so that it was now at the root) and changed the stylesheet link from `../stylesheets/normal.css` to `stylesheets/normal.css`, the font DID display. I believe this to be a browser bug. What browser are you using?

Comment: I am using Opera, Mozilla, and Google Chrome in my laptop it work well in anyone of those. If you opened the RAR you will get the font and codes to be stored locally, meaning stored in your localhost.If you put the extracted file
for example in Desktop and click the foo/index.html the following font didn't work you need to use this way '<style>@import url('
https: //fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arvo');</style>'. The following answer above has been updated. @Belthian

Answer (score 0):

Relative URLs can be tricky, but beginning with no slash is the same as `./`, which means to begin from the current directory. Beginning with two dots and a slash (`../`) moves up one directory to the parent. Beginning with just a slash (`/`) goes to root.

I think you're focusing on the stylesheet, but you should be looking at the URL of the font within the stylesheet. Your font is referenced to the current directory, with no slash:

`url("fonts/example.woff")`

To avoid any weirdness, it's probably a good idea to make asset references inside the stylesheet absolute even if the stylesheet itself is accessed by a relative reference.

Comment: This is a website that is accessed on the same machine that hosts the website. The website is not online. To access the website, I visit `file:///home/username/project/foo/index.html`, where the font isn't loaded but the stylesheet is. If I place `/home/username/project/foo/index.html` at `/home/username/project/index.html` and update the file so that the stylesheet is `stylesheets/normal.css` instead of `../stylesheets/normal.css`, both the font and the stylesheet load correctly. The issue only occurs when `index.html` is inside of a directory that is a sibling of the `stylesheets` directory.